# How to return a value from OnCompleteListener while creating user with email and password in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

The code which I am trying to write is

```
private String val;
    public String checkEmail(){

        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        db.collection("cities").whereEqualTo("cities", "Boston").get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            val = "City exists";
                        }else{
                            val = "City does not exist";
                        }
                    }
                });
        return val;
    }
```

This code returns `val` as `null` instead of the values. How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure this because the call is async, change your method to non return value (void) and create an interface callback to return value when the call is complete. Try this..

```
interface CityCallback {
     void isCityExist(boolean exist);
}

public void checkEmail(CityCallback cityCallback){
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("cities").whereEqualTo("cities", "Boston").get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        cityCallback.isCityExist(true);
                    }else{
                        cityCallback.isCityExist(false);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

to call the method it will be like this

```
checkEmail(new CityCallback {
      @Override
      public void isCityExist(boolean exist) {
           if (exist) {
              // set the value of variable val or anything
           } else {
              // set the value of variable val or anything
           }
      }
});
```

i hope it help you